# In app purchase premium upgrade lost when updating to new version of the app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

A customer has reported that she first bought the premium version through In app purchase. She then updated the app when a new version was released. The upgrade was lost then, so she lost the premium features of the app and were back with the free limited version. It was not possible to buy the full version again, because Google said "You already have bought this app, you can not buy it again". Why does this happen? I have implemented In app purchase according to the official guidelines.

Comment: Could you provide more info. What is the premium feature type? say Managed or subscription? The feature is purchased, but when you upgrade the app, you might be blocking the feature. If possible provide any code sample what you were doing?

Comment: It is managed. Here is code:  http://www.mobile-visuals.com/InappHandler.java